# Сделать поиск слов по тексту введенных в Edit через пробел

Tags: delphi, строки, поиск

Ищу строки в текстовом файле, по ключевым словам, используя функцию Pos.

Код:

```
If pos ('Slovo1 Slovo2',s) > 0 then
  writeln(fayl, S);
```

Не пойму, как подключить **Edit1.Text**, чтобы можно было задавать в **Edit1** не одно слово а много слов, используя пробел как разделитель между словами.

Вот так изменил (Но в таком случае ищется все что задано в edit, целиком):

```
If pos (Edit1.text,s) > 0 then
  writeln(fayl, S);
```

Comment: @Dima, Дмитрий, посмотрите, я обновил вопрос, переделав по вашему коду. Но у меня почему то ищет только по одному слову. Что то сделал я не так...?

Comment: Ваш код не компилировал, но, честно говоря, свой код я тестировал - заданное ищет. Могу предположить лишь, что введенный текст в `TEdit` не совпадает с текстом, прочитанным из файла в плане регистра. Функция [Pos](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Pos@RawByteString@RawByteString.html) регистрозависима. Т.е., если в компонент `TEdit` написать: **"тЕкст"**, а в читаемом файле будет слово **"текст"**, то ничего найдено не будет, следовательно, в выходной файл ничего не запишется.

Comment: @Dima, Текст в edit совпадает с текстом что в файле, только что проверил. Странно что же может быть ?...

Comment: Денис, я обнаружил ошибку в своем коде. Странно, что на легком примере все сработало,что меня и сбило с толку. Но я исправил досадный баг. Скомпилируйте Ваш пример снова - все должно работать. Прошу прощения!

Comment: @Dima, Я обновил код в теме, посмотрите... А теперь идет поиск только по последнему слову... Не могу понять где прокол ?... Заранее благодарен... То есть если в тексте есть цифры и буквы... То такой косяк...

Comment: Цифры и буквы? На сей раз я протестировал код тщательнее: создал два файла (чтение/запись) и проверил различные строки. Находит всё, что было введено в `TEdit` и "разбито" пробелом. Дайте тогда пример строки, может дело в функции Pos.

Comment: @Dima, Все, только разобрался. Оказывается, у меня, не была, правильно поставлена скобка во втором примере. Все заработало... 1000 извинений и низкий поклон!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для "постройки" массива строк из текста, введенного в `TEdit`, необходимо воспользоваться циклом и реализовать простейший парсинг строки.

**Ответ изменен! Добавлена рекомендация по повышению производительности кода**
*Спасибо пользователю Alekcvp!*

Например, таким образом:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StringArray: Array of String;
  InputString: String;
  OutputWord: String;
  StringToFind: String;
  CurrentChar: Char;
  StringLength: Integer;
  Capacity: Integer;
  WordCount: Integer;
  Delta: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  InputString := Edit1.Text;
  StringLength := Length(InputString);
  Capacity := 0;
  WordCount := 0;

  for i:=1 to StringLength do
    begin
      CurrentChar := InputString[i];
      OutputWord := OutputWord + CurrentChar;

      // Встречен пробел или цикл достиг конца строки (текста)
      if ((CurrentChar = ' ') or (i = StringLength)) and (i <> 1) then
        begin
          // Изменяем размерность массива
          if Capacity = WordCount then
            begin
              if Capacity > 64 then
                Delta := Capacity div 4
              else
              if Capacity > 8 then
                Delta := 16
              else
                Delta := 4;
              Inc(Capacity, Delta);
              SetLength(StringArray, Capacity);
            end;

          // Записываем готовую строку (найденное слово) в массив
          StringArray[WordCount] := Trim(OutputWord);

          // Увеличиваем счетчик слов
          Inc(WordCount);

          // "Обнуляем" строку для последующих проходов цикла
          OutputWord := '';
        end;
    end;

  // Строка, в которой происходит поиск слов из массива строк (просто пример)
  StringToFind := 'StringToFind';

  // Поиск подстроки в массиве строк
  for i:=Low(StringArray) to High(StringArray) do
    begin
      if Pos(StringArray[i], StringToFind) > 0 then
        ShowMessage('Found!');
    end;
end;
```

Массив динамический, его размерность увеличивается всякий раз, когда определено новое слово или цикл дошел до конца введенного в `TEdit` текста.

Comment: Дмитрий, посмотрите, я обновил вопрос, переделав по вашему коду. Но у меня почему то ищет только по одному слову. Что то сделал я не так...?

Comment: Для учебного кода нормально, но в реальном приложении делать в цикле такие вещи: ` SetLength(StringArray, Length(StringArray) + 1);` - это, во-первых, замедляет код, а, во-вторых, может приводить к фрагментации памяти. Лучше выделить один раз с запасом, если не хватит - в процессе довыделить (тоже с запасом), а по завершении - уменьшить. Можете посмотреть как это сделано во всяких TList.

Comment: @Alekcvp, честно говоря, я думал о том, чтобы до начала цикла выделить массив, соответствующий по количеству элементов длине строки в `TEdit`. А потом отказался от этой идеи, поскольку пришлось бы в конце "обрезать массив" через `SetLength`. После Вашего замечания я провел замеры скорости выполнения цикла. Так вот, с текущим вариантом реализации, выполнение 100 циклов с перебором всего текста в `TEdit` составило 0,0312 мс. Вариант со ступенчатым выделением памяти (как в `TList`) позволил снизить время до 0,0272 мс. Количество слов для теста было 601. Разница несущественна.

Comment: @Alekcvp, хотя проведя тесты с 3000 слов, разница оказалась уже 0,0263 мс. в пользу варианта со ступенчатым выделением памяти. Сомневаюсь, что кто-либо будет парсить такое количество текста в однострочном `TEdit`, но Вашу подсказку добавлю в код, уж больно полезная фича, хотя немного "тяжела" для этой задачи.

Comment: @Dima, ну понятно что эта задача такого не требует. Но потом народ привыкает так делать и вот уже цикл на тысячи итераций с `Result := Result + Char;`. Вообще перераспределения памяти в циклах, без крайней необходимости, стоит избегать ИМХО.